# can we pass options to tcl source command in tcl 8.5

Tags: linux, scripting, arguments, tcl

I am using this command to source get.tcl file and giving options 'verbose' and 'instant':

> *source -verbose -instant get.tcl*

the above command worked for me in tcl 8.4 but showing this error in tcl 8.5

> source  (script wrong # args: should be "source_orig ?-encoding name?
>   fileName"

if I write only

> source get.tcl

It get passed in tcl 8.5

Is there any change related to this in tcl 8.5?

Comment: I don't think Tcl source ever supported these arguments, perhaps your Tcl 8.4 interpreter has non-standard modifications?

Comment: @ColinMacleod yes there was some modification in my tcl 8.4 interpreter when I checked after your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `source` command only accepts one option (since 8.5), `-encoding`, which is used to specify what encoding the file being read is in (instead of the default guess of encoding as returned by `encoding system`). All it does is read the file into memory and (internally-equivalent-to-) `eval` the contents.

You can write to any variable you want prior to doing the `source`, including global variables like `argv`. With that (plus appropriate use of `uplevel` and `catch`, as required, and maybe also `interp create`) you can simulate running the script as a subprocess. But it's probably easier to not have the file expect to be handling arguments like that, and instead for it to define a command that you call immediately after the sourcing.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arguments to your sourced file by doing the following:

```
set ::argv [list -verbose -instant]
source get.tcl
```

I recommend using:

```
set ::argv [list -- -verbose -instant]
```

The -- will stop tclsh from processing any arguments after the --.
Sometimes tclsh will recognize an argument that is meant for your
program and process it.  Your programs will need to know about 
the -- and handle it appropriately.